# Not Found: /products/images/DSroadmap.png Not Found: /products/images/codewall.jpg [26/Jan/2020 22:13:36]

Tags: python, html, django

I am unable to load images from my MEDIAL_URL on a html page. Below is my code for uploading images, media url and the html. Any any help will be highly appreciated.

```
html:
    <div class="row">   
        {% for item in items %}
          <div class='col-sm-3'>
           {% for item in item.itemimage_set.all %}
            {% if item.featured %}
              <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image }}">
            {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
          {{ item.title }}
          {{ item.price }}
    </div>
        {% cycle "" "" "" "</div><br/><hr/><div class='row'>" %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

model:

    class ItemImage(models.Model):
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
        featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)



        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.item.title

media url & root:

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
```

Comment: Did you try using `item.image.url` instead of `item.image`?

Comment: No problem! I added it as the answer in case anyone else stumbles upon the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To access an image URL from a `FileField()` object, you need to access it via the `.url` property.

In this case, it would be `item.image.url` instead of `item.image`, which returns just the object (and not the URL you need).

> Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url